# Problems using SerializeObject and DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am using SerializeObject as follows:

```
string info = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListaInfo[j]);
```

where ListaInfo is a viewmodel, but when trying to use DeserializeObject as follows:

```
InfoViewModel t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<infoViewModel>(info);
```

I get a stackoverflow error because the viewmodel has a property like this:

```
public string FECHA_DIA {
                                get {
                                    return FECHA == null ? "" : FECHA.Value.Day.ToString();                                        
                                }
                                set {
                                    FECHA_DIA = "";
                                }
                            }
```

How can I use DeserializeObject by having that property in the viewModel?

Comment: `public string FECHA_DIA` this is your property... and when you doing `FECHA_DIA = "";` inside set, you are calling set again, which calls set again, which calls set again, and so on.... causing stackoverflow exception.

Comment: You can actually remove the `set` part of this property if you already have `get` and `set` both for `FECHA` property.

Comment: Can  you post  the whole json and class, pls?